# How to correctly use ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="ad.selected" ng-options="option.name for option in ad.available track by option.value"></select>
```

Where is my mistake? Why is this set not selected?

```
options: [{value:"0",name:"First"},{value:"1",name:"Second"}]
```

Value from server

```
ad.selected // 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how it works,

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in ad.available"  ng-model="ad.selected"></select>
```

This generates,

```
<select>
  <option value="option.value">option.name</option>
  ...
</select>
```

`option.name` will be the name and `option.value` will display the value.

`ad.selected` will have to be the set as the value that is available in the array. 1 or 0.

Updated the fiddle
[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shammelburg/hsyhmgc9/5/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here;

```
ng-options="option.name for option in ad.available track by option.value"
```

That one should be like this;

```
ng-options="option.name for option in options track by option.value"
```

Comment: For ad.available i assign options     ad = {available : options}